# What do Italians call the striped doorway curtains seen commonly in Burano and elsewhere?

Tags: italy, local-customs, venice, local-knowledge

Is there an Italian name for the doorway curtains found especially in towns in the Venice lagoon, such as Burano? How would a local go about purchasing these?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd guess a local would go to a local store and hand over cash and get the doorway covering of their choice /s

Comment: tenda da sole a caduta

Comment: I think you will find more relevant information on our sister site about Italian (https://italian.stackexchange.com/). I have mixed feeling what it is the more appropriate site, but possibly it depends on the kind of answer you want (more linguistic and similar words; or more touristic/cultural/use)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi yes, I wasn't sure either... I will try over on the other site as well, but I do think this is more of a cultural/travel question, because certain Italian towns do not do this, and others have them on nearly every door

Comment: @PeterM I'm sure you're not far off, but this striped drape style is a little too distinct and coordinated to just be a random shopping choice ;)

Comment: @NeanDerThal this is spot-on in style, but I'm looking for the doorway coverings that you could pull aside, and "tenda da sole a caduta" seem to be more like awnings that are fixed in place at top and bottom? Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @Ryan Given that this is around Venice, it wouldn't surprise me if there were restrictions on how the locals can decorate their houses.

Comment: @Ryan I am not Italian, I just used google and found the same style listed as "tenda da sole a caduta"

Answer (score 1):

Amazon sells them under the name "Tende da Sole a Caduta"

[image]